# Free Testing Tools

Tags: asp.net, testing

We have built an ASP.NET application and we would like to do functional, regression, load , and stress etc. tests.

Would you please let me know if there are any free tools to these tests?

Answer (score 3):

[Lightweight Test Framework](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20QA)

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

[Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: dead link: Lightweight Test Framework

Answer (score 1):

One option is Telerik's [WebAii framework](http://www.telerik.com/products/webaii-testing-framework.aspx).