# ASP.Net Testing Suite?

Tags: asp.net, testing

I'm in the process of researching testing options for .Net development particularly ASP.Net.
What testing tools do you swear by? NUnit, Selenium, RhinoMocks are my current apps in my toolbox but what do others have to offer for a more complete testing coverage?

No budget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swear by NUnit, Selenium and then a number of other little tools like YSlow, Firebug

I did a talk at Google Test Automation Conference http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQgDDAan4rM where I show how you can mix Selenium, NUnit and Yslow to get an idea of how the user is experiencing the system.

I have started using JsTestDriver as well and think that is really good for unit testing JavaScript The video from the same conference is here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDKGGZv-T4M

All of those are free and most are open source

Answer (score 1):

> Kzu and friends have a new pet project called Moq, which may be the coolest derivative open source project name ever. -Scott Hanselman
>   http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MoqLinqLambdasAndPredicatesAppliedToMockObjects.aspx

Haven't gotten around to trying [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) out yet but I've seen Hanselman talk about it in a couple of his blog posts, probably worth checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to [ASP.NET Free testing tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477616/asp-net-free-testing-tools)